# Symfony 1.4 mailer: change the subject depending on the environment?

Tags: symfony1, mailer

I use Symfony 1.4 and I have two different configurations for the prod and dev environment, the former use the single_address as delivery strategy, and the latter use the spool:

```
dev:
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      delivery_strategy: single_address
      delivery_address:  my@email
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
[...]

prod:
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      delivery_strategy: spool
      spool_class:       Swift_PropelSpool
      spool_arguments:   [ MailMessage, message, getSpooledMessages ]      
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
```

I was wondering if Symfony could add automatically, in the dev environment, some text to the mail subject (i.e. [DEVELOPMENT EMAIL - PLEASE DISCARD]).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the part where you are sending the e-mail you can use the `sfConfig::get('sf_environment')` variable to set your subject.

```
<?php
$subject = 'Some Subject';
if (sfConfig::get('sf_environment') == 'dev')
{
  $subject = '[DEVELOPMENT EMAIL - PLEASE DISCARD] ' . $subject;
}
```

To do this globally you can use a base Mailer class as described in http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/11-Emails#chapter_11_email_messages_as_classes